# Why is the layout different in the simulator as compared to the screen in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I just started learning programming in android and I wanted to know why is the layout and the colour of the navigation bar in the simulator is different to what is being shown in android studio? Please see the image attached.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LV0z.jpg)

Comment: Above AndroidStudio design view there is button to select theme. You selected Material, but that doesn't have to be theme applied in application.

Comment: In the `styles.xml` file, you have defined a different theme for that Activity when it is ran on the device. In the preview, you have selected "Material"

Comment: @cricket_007 Oh right, I though it would change automatically based on the theme I select

Comment: Nope, it is just a preview window that you can quickly view the different themes. It would be nice if it also changed the theme value in the XML